# Why is my "third" ethernet interface "eno1" but others are enp1s0, enp2s0, enp4s0?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, 22.04

Just installed 22.04 Server on a box with an Intel I225-V Ethernet Controller and four external RJ454 connectors labelled, from left to right, ETH3, ETH2, ETH1, ETH0. `lshw -class network`produces the following, from which I have omitted all lines that are the same for each interface:

```
   *-network                 
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       serial: 60:be:b4:00:7d:e5
       resources: irq:22 memory:a1700000-a17fffff memory:a1800000-a1803fff
  *-network
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       serial: 60:be:b4:00:7d:e6
       resources: irq:23 memory:a1500000-a15fffff memory:a1600000-a1603fff
  *-network
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       serial: 60:be:b4:00:7d:e7
       resources: irq:20 memory:a1300000-a13fffff memory:a1400000-a1403fff
  *-network
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       serial: 60:be:b4:00:7d:e8
       resources: irq:21 memory:a1100000-a11fffff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
```

I know that the first interface, enp1s0, is the rightmost RJ45 connector because that's what I've plugged into for ssh and `ip a` shows it as the only one with an ip address.

Why would the third interface have a different "kind" of logical name? I don't think it will make any functional difference, but curiosity drove me to ask.

Edit to add: just noticed in the lshw output that eno1 has the lowest irq number. Whether this is a hint about my question I don't know.

Comment: It should be `enp3s0`, because of the PCI slot. But if you configured the name somewhere to `eno1`, then it is OK. If you didn't, then it is a mystery. `eno` is for onboard devices.

Comment: You can look in `dmesg` output, maybe there is some hint. Probably BIOS set one port as an "onboard" device.

Comment: I didn't configure anything that would affect the names!

Comment: Assuming that you didn't rename it in /etc/netplan/*.yaml, then there's a firmware setting for the Intel I225-V Ethernet Controller that allows you to set the port name for what would normally be enp3s0 (port 3 slot 0). Check the Intel web site for a utility for that card. It's also possible that it can be changed using an "options" setting in the driver.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible , that three ethetnets are built in chipset, one is created with pci-to-ethernet bridge.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers my question:

```
~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i eno1    
[    3.324759] igc 0000:03:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth2  
~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i enp1s0  
[    3.139736] igc 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
```

Thanks to @Pilot6 in a comment to my question for directing me to dmesg.

I suppose this happens at each boot. The kernel driver igc doesn't like the old traditional "eth" names.

@Pilot6 also mentioned that "eno" is for onboard devices. `lspci` output indicates
`DeviceName: Onboard - RTK Ethernet` for the third ethernet interface, and *only* for that interface. That line is absent from the output for the other ones. So perhaps that interface is -- strangely, to my mind -- indeed different with respect to hardware. Strangely because I'd think the different one would be first or last of the four.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/systemd.net-naming-scheme.7.html) the 'eno1' device might get that number from the firmware. Maybe someone set it to '1' with some management tool / via BIOS or similar?

```
       ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD=prefixonumber
           This name is set based on the numeric ordering information given by the firmware for
           on-board devices. The name consists of the prefix, letter o, and a number specified by
           the firmware. This is only available for PCI devices.
```

But very interesting, I'd like to know too, once you've found out for sure :D